# Rock Paper Scissors javascript using matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix

Hello everyone I am new here and am currently taking a javascript course at my university for my software development degree. I am running into an issue in my rock paper scissors lizard spock final project. My professor has given us QUnit Tests that can check our code but I am not very good at understanding how the errors show me whats wrong as I don't really understand how to get this code to work. So far I have created some objects and gave them properties and methods. i also created a matrix to capture and retain the variations of win conditions. however I don't understand how to create my final method I need: getWinner. In our rubric it states the following:

"Method that will evaluate who won the game. Should update the wins, losses, and rate of each player. Should also set the "winner" property to the name of the winning player."

Here is my game.js file that I am working on. At the bottom is where I am stumped with how to start this getWinner function. I have something started but its not responding to my unit tests. I can post the code if need be as well. As well as my other file which is another object.

```
var Game = function(){
this.running = false;
this.name = "RPSLS";
this.players = [];
    this.addPlayer = function(name){
        var player = new Player(name);
        this.players.push(player);
        return player;
    };
    this.getPlayer = function(number){
        var player_number = number - 1;
        return this.players[player_number];
    };
    this.setHand = function(number, hand){
        var p = this.getPlayer(number);
        p.hand = hand;
    };

    this.matrix = {
        rock: {
            scissors: true,
            lizard: true
            },

        paper: {
            rock: true,
            spock: true
            },

        scissors: {
            paper: true,
            lizard: true
            },

        lizard: {
            spock: true,
            paper: true
            },

        spock: {
            rock: true,
            scissors: true

            }

    };


    this.getWinner = function(){
            var player1 = this.getPlayer();
            var player2 = this.getPlayer();
            if ( this.matrix [ player1 ] == [ player2 ] ) {

            } else if ( this.matrix [player1] [player2] ) {};
        }
```

};

Thank you for reading through this and trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are mainly mixing up `Object` and `Array`. The `Object` in question is the key-value list in curly braces (your `matrix` variable). You get and set a key in of such a list by calling its name: `matrix["key"] = value`.
Such a key-value list can be nested. Deeply. See for example JSON. Parsing such deeply nested lists is complicated and error prone (there are ready-to-use libraries for JSON) so you do not use them if not absolutely necessary.

I simplified your ansatz to some extend but used arrays and objects where possible.

```
var Game = function(){
// unused
this.running = false;
this.name = "RPSLS";
// Object (key-value list) to hold the players
this.allplayers = {};
// Object "Player"" to hold one player
var Player = function(){
    this.name = "";
    this.hand = "";
};
this.addPlayer = function(pname){
    // get memory for one new player
    var player = new Player();
    // set the name of the player
    player.name = pname;
    // put the player-object into the player-list
    this.allplayers[pname] = player;
    return player;
};
this.getPlayer = function(pname){
    return this.allplayers[pname];
};
this.setHand = function(pname, phand){
    this.allplayers[pname].hand = phand;
};

  /*
 Rock <-> Paper <-> Scissor <-> Lizard <-> Spock (Vulcan)

 If column beats row -> 1
 If column looses to row -> -1
 If tie -> 0


       0  1  2  3  4
       R  P  S  L  V
 0  R  0 -1  1  1 -1
 1  P  1  0 -1 -1  1
 2  S -1  1  0  1 -1 
 3  L -1  1 -1  0  1
 4  V  1 -1  1 -1  0
 */

// translate name to place in table above
this.rpslvEnum = {
  rock: 0,
  paper: 1,
  scissor: 2,
  lizard: 3,
  spock: 4
};

this.scheme = [
                [ 0, -1,  1,  1, -1],
                [ 1,  0, -1, -1,  1],
                [-1,  1,  0,  1, -1],
                [-1,  1, -1,  0,  1],
                [ 1, -1,  1, -1,  0]
              ];

this.getWinner = function(){
        var player1 = this.addPlayer("Kirk");
        var player2 = this.addPlayer("Uhura");
        this.setHand("Kirk","scissor");
        this.setHand("Uhura","spock");
        var result =  this.scheme[this.rpslvEnum[player1.hand]]
                                 [this.rpslvEnum[player2.hand]];
        switch(result){
          case 0: return "It's a tie";
          case 1: return "Player one had won";
          case -1: return "Player two had won";
          default: throw new Error("Something unexpected happend in " + this.name);break;
        }
   };
};
var g = new Game();
console.log(g.getWinner());
```

It lacks a lot of the obligatory Checks&Balances and is quite unorganized but I hope it suffices to get along now, otherwise…well…you know where to ask ;-)